# non repeating characters of a string

Tags: algorithm

Given a string *Str of ASCII characters, write the pseudo code to remove the duplicate elements present in them. For example, if the given string is "Potato", then, the output has to be "Pota". Additional constraint is, the algorithm has to be in-place.

I have written a program with bool array of 255 elements and keep their value to be false.while traversing the string i change their value to  true to mark them as visited and in this way i have another string of unique values.In this way i am using constant space.Is there any better way of doing this.please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the words "another string", so maybe, just maybe, you have 2 strings? The idea of in-place is that you do it in the same string. But maybe you just meant "another string contents", so yes, then it's fine. To clarify: you have the string given, and assign two pointers to the beginning of it, then advance your reader-pointer reading one char at a time, writing (and thus incrementing your writer-pointer) only if the char was not already in your 255-table.

Answer (score 2):

You need a boolean array the **size of your alphabet** (e.g. 26 for lower case latin alphabet). Then you traverse the string, and for each letter you check if the corresponding field of the array is true. If not, set it to true. Then remove the letter. To remove the letters in place, keep a counter of how many letters have been removed already, and copy each letter to the left by that much. Since this sounds like homework, I leave the writing of the pseudo-code up to you.

Answer (score 0):

To make your solution in place, instead of using the output array just shift left the next characters in the input array into the current position whenever you want to remove a character.

Pseudocode:

```
for each position in input_array:
     c=input_array[position]
     if we have already seen c
         shift left all characters position+1 by one character.
         position=position-1 // so that we process this character in the next iteration
     else
         mark c as seen
     end if
```

Comment: This algorithm will run into an infinite loop after the first replace. If you copy character `i+1` to `i`, and then look at `i` again, you will find that you have already seen that character, and so you will copy `i+1` to `i` and look at `i` again and so on...

Comment: but now you've made it an n^2 solution, which i don't think will suffice if this is a homework problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

```
seen is array of 256 boolean, initially all false
output position is start of string
for each position in string:
    c is char at position
    if seen[c] is false:
        set seen[c] to true
        set char at output position to c
        increment output position
```

The output string ends at `output position`. Don't forget to set the length of the output string or add its terminator as appropriate (depending on the programming language).